# Creating a treeview with nodes in a picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, gdi, treenode

I'm working on a school project and need a bit of help.
What we have to do is a treeview but in a picturebox.
I have nodes at my disposal that look like this:

ID;NAME;PARENT;LEFT;RIGHT
eg.: 1;a;0;1;10

These nodes are taken from a TXT file, I'm doing that using a streamreader.

```
      static Tree Load()
    {
        List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\tree.txt"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] line = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
                nodes.Add(new TreeNode() {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(line[0]),
                    Name = line[1],
                    ParentId = Convert.ToInt32(line[2]),
                    Left = Convert.ToInt32(line[3]),
                    Right = Convert.ToInt32(line[4]),
                });
            }
        }

        n*log2(n)     = 10000 + 1000 O->W
        W -> O   1000 + x*log2(x)

        nodes = nodes.OrderBy(x => x.Left).ToList();
```

I somehow have to draw these nodes in a correct order and sorted by their parent in a picturebox. 
But I don't know how.

This is what it should look like, with the exception that it must be in a picturebox and not in cmd.
[image: This is what it should look like]

Comment: Does it havbe to be a picture box. The `TreeView` class has a `BackgroundPicture` property.

Comment: It has to be a picturebox.

Comment: If you just want to draw it use the Paint event and a fixed width font and draw it..